# Finding Foreign Legion recruits from WW2?

Tags: military-records, world-war-2

I'd like to contact the Foreign Legion to find out about one of their recruits from WW2 - what is the best way to do it?

I've already sent an email but there hasn't been a reply in weeks.  Would they provide information if the death certificate of the person in question was provided?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Please take a moment to check out the [help] to find out more about the site works. You can add more info to your Q at any time by using the edit link underneath.  Where did you get the contact information for the email you sent?

Comment: I can't remember and I've since cleared out my sent folder.  I searched for French Foreign Legion and used the email from what would have looked like the official site.  Do you know the correct email address for them?

Answer (score -1):

This site looks like the best place to start from:

[Those Who Fought in the French Foreign Legion During World War Two](http://french-genealogy.typepad.com/genealogie/2017/07/those-who-fought-in-the-french-foreign-legion-during-world-war-two.html)

Comment: This would be a batter answer if it did not just provide a link, but summarised the key information.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think the person actually got a chance to do any fighting with the Legion, they might still have been in training when they left it.

Comment: If you let me have some further details on him I could try run a trace on him and see what might come of it.

Comment: Well I suppose that the person must have signed up in some way prior to under going training or whatever. I therefore suppose that the  only thing to do in the circumstances would appear to be to go to the site and enter the name and see what might comes of it. You might also care to note that, if a person was wounded in service with them that the person would thereby automatically qualify to become a French Citizen  as a result of it. Also it would be difficult to say how concerned that they might or might not have been as to what name a person might have used to sign up with.